# Tracking user activities to build individual user profile & suggestions

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I am about to build a web shop and need to come up with a solution of tracking user information, and based upon that suggest the users products they may like too and so build an individual user profile (what they like).

Information to be tracked/used for the algorithm, I thought should include:

- past orders
- wish list/bookmarks/favourites...
- search terms entered
- products viewed (and here also track and consider the "drop-off"-quote, meaning wether a user closes the site/goes back immediately or looks at more pictures/scrolls down (viewport) etc)

Products are assigned to categories as well as different attributes such as colors, tags etc. The table `product` has relations with `color`, `category`, etc.

> **product**
>   id_product
>   price
>   timestamp_added
>
> **color**
>   id_color
>   ...
>
> **product_color**
>   id_product_color
>   id_product
>   id_color

The questions are:

1) How would you structure a database to track e.g. products viewed? Should it be just like this?:

> **product_viewed**
>   id_product_viewed
>   id_product
>   id_user
>   timestamp

2) If I want to calculate e.g. the users top 3 favourite colors based on colors of products the user bought, put on their wish list, bookmarked, viewed: can it be handled from a performance point of view to calculate which products should be recommended to this when querying the database every single time? Or do you update a user profile from time to time, storing only the already calculated favourite color at the moment based upon the tracked data and use the stored calculated data to find products that match this information?

How do big sites like facebook, amazon or pinterest do this? On pinterest you get suggestions for items you may like based on what items you clicked on before. How do they handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your schema for product_viewed is OK.

As for their three favorite colors, try this untested code:

```
select c.name, count(*) as rank
from product_viewed pv
JOIN product_color pc on pc.id_product = pv.id_product
JOIN color c on pc.id_color = c.id_color
where pv.id_user = 1
group by c.name
order by rank desc
limit 3
```

Given indexes on the ids used to join the tables and a reasonable limit on the number of items viewed, this should have decent performance.  Down the road, you might only look at their most recent 100 products, etc., just to keep it from growing forever.  (Or, as you suggest, caching).

There's no magic to this, so it's probably similar to that those other sites are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it with tables like you just wrote is a good way.
Facebook and etc. is doing it that way as well.

But for more efficiency, they use so called B-Trees.

Comment: ok, thanks for this! I know b-trees only from indexing, I will take a look on that, thank you! what would you say about 2) in my question? How would you calculate the favourite color?

Comment: while I've just googled what a B-Tree is, would it be possible to given an explanation as to why someone like Facebook would use a B-Tree instead of a different solution?  i.e. why are B-Trees the best?

Comment: With a massive DB like Facebook has, time to provide information matters. A classic tree wouldn't be the best solution for that. With a B-Tree, you have all leafs in one level and so the access to the information requires just one step: `Database -> Information`. Instead of a classic tree: `Database -> Profile -> Name -> Information`. But as far as I know, this is going beyond MySQL. A B-Tree is a little struggle to setup.